# Writable nested serializers User and User profile doesn't work

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to create a user registration endpoint through django rest framework with his profile and it shows me that I have not created an explicit .create() method for my serializer. What I'm missing?

here's my models.py

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    language = models.CharField(max_length=4, default='es')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "%s - %s" % (self.user, self.language)
```

my serializers.py

```
class ProfileCreateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = [
        'language',
        ]


class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    profile = ProfileCreateSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = [
        'username',
        'profile',
        ]

def create (self, validated_data):
    user = User.objects.create(username=validated_data['username'])
    user.set_password(User.objects.make_random_password())
    profile_data = validated_data.pop('profile')
    Profile.objects.create(user=user, **profile_data)
    user.save()
```

My views.py

```
class ProfileCreateAPIView(CreateAPIView):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    model = Profile
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
```

Comment: Is this really the indentation of your source code ? Can you paste the full traceback please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks OK, but your indentation looks wrong: the `.create()` method needs to be a method on the serializer, so it should be indented to the same level as the `class Meta:` statement.

It should probably look like this (note the indent on the `create()` method):

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    profile = ProfileCreateSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = [ 'username', 'profile', ]

    def create (self, validated_data):
        user = User.objects.create(username=validated_data['username'])
        user.set_password(User.objects.make_random_password())
        profile_data = validated_data.pop('profile')
        Profile.objects.create(user=user, **profile_data)
        user.save()
```

More examples at [DRF Docs (Saving Instances)](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#saving-instances), in case that helps.