# How to add data into 2 separate tables in django rest_framework?

Tags: python, django

I have created a simple API and want to add data into 2 tables.
For example, I have created 2 tables in models.py

```
class User(models.Model):
    userid = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length= 100)
    age = models.IntegerField()
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'user'

class Detail(models.Model):
    address = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    phone = models.IntegerField()
    details = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'detail'
```

serializers.py

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    name=serializers.CharField(required=True)
    age = serializers.IntegerField(required=True)
    gender = serializers.CharField(required=True)
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields= '__all__'

class DetailSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    address = serializers.CharField(required=True)
    phone = serializers.IntegerField(required=True)
    details= serializers.CharField(required=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Detail
        fields= '__all__'
```

suppose I am passing the JSON data as

```
{
"name" : "abc",
"age" : 20,
"gender" : "Male",
"address" : "xyz",
"phone" : 454545454,
"details" : "lorem epsum"
}
```

is it possible to insert data into both tables?.
name, age & gender should be inserted into the User table & and address, phone & details in the Detail table.
I have tried many things hence I have nothing to show in views.py

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ye, this is completely possible, I have two solutions for this problem-

Assuming `User` and `Detail` are not correlated, models. You can simply create an API View like given below and save the data manually to both the tables.

```
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response
from .serializers import (
    UserSerializer,
    DetailSerializer
)

class UserAPIView(APIView):
    def post(self, request, format=None):

        name = request.data.get('name')
        age = request.data.get('age')
        gender = request.data.get('gender')
        address = request.data.get('address')
        phone = request.data.get('phone')
        details = request.data.get('details')

        user_serializer = UserSerializer(data={"name": name, "age": age, "gender": gender})
        detail_serializer = DetailSerializer(data={"address": address, "phone": phone, "details": details})

        if user_serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
            user_serializer.save()

        if detail_serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
            detail_serializer.save()

        return Response({'status': 'Success'})
```

I would suggest you connect your `User` and `Detail` tables through One to One relation, if both are used for storing user information, your task of storing the information in single-shot request would become easier with the help of nested serializers.

Otherwise do not separate the information in one table, just put everything in one table if the information belongs to all the users.

Comment: I am getting an error```TypeError at /api/useradd/
__init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given```

Comment: Are you defining your urlpatterns path correctly for this API class, because Class Based View requires `.as_view()` to use it as a view function.
You can define the path something like this-
`path('api/useradd/', UserAPIView.as_view()),`

Comment: thanks for reply, I have solved the error but now the issue is I cannot add data in both the tables. can you help me with models.py with proper relation so that userid can be mapped the same I don't have to add that manually?

Comment: In the original answer to this question, I have stated in the 2nd last point that you have to connect both the tables through One to One connection, then you can use a nested serializer to save the data in one request.
Please refer to this Stackoverflow thread-
https://stackoverflow.com/a/43798901/8550926